# Update an application on the click of a Button

Tags: gui-construction, interface, button

I am finishing my first program in Wolfram *Mathematica* 10 and if I have almost completed is essentially thanks to this valuable forum soon where I will try to help too.

Basically, now I have this problem: to make work a routine I used `Button["Start", Module[{}, 'routine']]`. Unfortunately, in this program you need to change the routine manually and then later by clicking on "Start" I can not consider the changes by not clicking "Shift + Enter". How can I do?

---

You're right MarcoB.

In reference to the following portion of my program:

[image]

when I edit the data and then click on "Risolvi" variable "sol" is not updated, but it remains in the old values. How can I fix without having to click "Shift + Enter"?

---

Equivalently, because the following code does not work if you click on the button ??

```
Button["Update", Module[{},
Function[cobj, SelectionMove[cobj, Cell, All];
    SelectionEvaluate[InputNotebook[]];]~Scan~
   TakeWhile[Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"], # =!= EvaluationCell[] &];
  SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell];]]
```

Comment: Manu, unfortunately I can't quite follow your explanation. Could you please provide examples? A minimal code example showcasing your problem would be best. You can always edit your question by using the "edit" link under the question.

Comment: I believe you should explain the following sentence further: _"Unfortunately, in this program you need to change the routine manually and then later by clicking on "Start" I can not consider the changes by not clicking "Shift + Enter""_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to produce an interactive application in which the user changes any of a set of parameters and then clicks on a button to indicate that the new parameters are to applied. That sort of thing is usually done within a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) expression. Here is an simple example of such an expression -- a solver for quadratic equations.

```
Manipulate[
  If[solve, solve = False; solution = update[]];
  Style[
    Column[{
      Row[{"Equation: ", TraditionalForm[a x^2 + b x + c == 0]}],
      Row[{"Solution: ", solution}]}],
    "Text"],
  Style["Coefficients", Bold, 11],
  {{a, 1}},
  {{b, 0}},
  {{c, -1}},
  {{solve, False}, None},
  {{solution, {{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}}}, None},
  Button["Solve", solve = True, ImageSize -> Automatic],
  Initialization :> (update[] := Solve[ a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]),
  TrackedSymbols :> {solve, solution},
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: quad]

Making changes to any of the three input fields has no effect until the **Solve** button is clicked. Since you are working on your first *Mathematica* program, there is probably a lot in the above example that will be new and strange to you, but I hope you will study it and that it will help you to develop the application you are working on.

**References**

$\quad \quad $[Introduction to Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html)

$\quad \quad $[Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html)